# Using MySQL with GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, mysql

I am storing all my features in MySQL db and I am getting them with ajax and adding to the OpenLayers map.
Now I have to many features and it's taking a lot of time to get all of them and adding them, so I want to load only little bit from them and show all the rest with GeoServer in a WMS layer.
I found some plugins but nothing really worked, and I didn't find any example.
The features are stores in the database as a regular table not as spatial data, only have attributes and a col for WKT for the location.

Is there a way to add this features from mysql db to GeoServer layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [MySQL spatial functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/geometry-property-functions.html) to cast your WKT or other attributes(such as float X/Y) to geometry objects, then point geoserver(with mysql plugins installed) to those tables and have geoserver render them.

Something like:

> UPDATE myPoints SET the_geom =  GeomFromText('POINT(long
>   ,lat)'));

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115106/convert-lat-lng-pairs-using-geomfromtextpoint1-1-and-insert-in-another-col) for a more complete answer for adding a geom column and updating it with whatever geographic information you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but *if* you need to have the geometry stored as WKT for whatever reason as opposed to a real geometry column, you could create a new layer based on a [SQL View](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) and create the geometry column on the fly using WKT->Geometry [conversion functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html#function_geomfromtext).

The catch is the layer is not modifiable.